# Regex to delete lines that match the second string?

Tags: regex, replace, duplicates, notepad++

I have long list of lines with a lot of situations like this, lines that have identical second word (second string after space), but the rest is different. I need to keep only one line with unique second string. Should work only for lines with the same second word which are always consecutive. For example, I have lines:

```
lineA 12345
lineB 12345
lineC 12345
lineD 788878
lineE 110881
lineF 110881
lineG 110881
lineH 287778
lineJ 251287
lineK 242424
lineL 242424
lineM 242424
```

to this result

```
lineA 12345
lineD 788878
lineE 110881
lineH 287778
lineJ 251287
lineK 242424
```

So, if second word in line is the match, delete all but one line.
I tried to create regex but it deletes only if first word match, I can't figure out how to do it for second word after space like in the example.

```
^(\S++).*\K(?:\R\1(?:\h.*|$))+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\S+\h+(\S+)\R\K(?:\S+\h+\1(?:\R|\Z))+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Qln1VD/1)

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Tested all and your seems to be more correct than others. It deletes lines not only with digits and working correct in this case: lines555 notdelete
lines5aa notdeleteww13

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all that dot-stars. They will slow things down. A proper and shorter version of yours would be:

```
^\S+\K( \S++)([^ ]+\1)+
```

and replace all matches with `$1`

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qffCji/1)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by capturing 2 groups, the first being the original line you want to keep `(\S+ (\d+))`, and the 2nd nested group which has the repeating digits (in your case the `(\d+)`).

We then find all subsequent lines (greedy) that match the pattern when the digits are repeated `\2` within `(?:\R\S+ \2)+`, and replace all of those with the first line `$1`.

> Find Regex Without Newlines: `(\S+ (\d+))(?:\R\S+ \2)+`
>   Replace All With: `$1`

**Edit:** Thanks Aaron for the newline trick! Learn something new after 16 years in npp!

Comment: You can use `\R` instead of `[\r\n]{1,2}`, it matches all the characters of a linefeed in a platform agnostic fashion. It's not implemented in many regex flavours but it is in the Boost engine Notepad++ uses.

Comment: My fault that I didn't say that second line can contain not only digit but letters only or letters mixed with digits so Aaron's version was more universal, don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: Also noticed that Aaron's regex deletes lines with similar words but I need exact match when deleting.

Comment: @redrednua Based on your question, it seemed like you had decent knowledge with Regular Expressions, so I focused on the use case you gave and assumed it would have been trivial to adjust the `\d` to any capture group such as another `\S` for any scenario.